# How to suspend open source support?

Tags: open-source, support

I'm the only active maintainer for an open source project, which receives support requests on various channels (Twitter, email, GitHub) almost daily. I'll be on vacation for the next three months, where I'll have very limited time to respond, let alone accept pull requests or resolve issues. What can I do to prevent disappointing people that put in time to ask a good question or write a proper bug report?

Comment: Why the negative votes?

Comment: Don't tell them you got 3 months of vacation ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are basically two ways to handle this.  Either hand it off to someone else, (which apparently is not an option here,) or simply post something on the project site and on "various channels" that you'll be unavailable for a while.  There really isn't much you can do beyond that.

Comment: And everyone is understanding that you need and take some vacations (and most of your users would take some too!).